# Boolean Property will not set to True

Tags: vb.net, boolean

I have a very basic form that literally has 1x label, textbox and button on it.

When the 'OK' button is clicked I need to check to see if the textbox (`txtServers`) is empty. If so, I set the property `ServersError` to `True`.

However, the `IIF` statement I used for this wasn't working. I then directly set `ServersError` to `True` (as you can see in the code), yet for some reason it's still returning `False` when I output the result directly afterwards.

Am I going mad, or is something strange happening here?! Thanks.

```
Public Class formServers

    Private m_ServersError As Boolean = False   ' Whether or not there is an error with the specified servers

    Public Property ServersError() As Boolean
        Get
            ServersError = m_ServersError
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Boolean)
            m_ServersError = ServersError
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        'Me.ServersError = IIf(Me.txtServers.Text.Length = 0, True, False)
        Me.ServersError = True
        MsgBox(Me.ServersError)
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no VB guy, but shouldn't it be like this?

```
Public Class formServers

    Private m_ServersError As Boolean = False   ' Whether or not there is an error with the specified servers

    Public Property ServersError() As Boolean
        Get
            ServersError = m_ServersError
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Boolean)
            m_ServersError = value ' <--------------- changed here
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        'Me.ServersError = IIf(Me.txtServers.Text.Length = 0, True, False)
        Me.ServersError = True
        MsgBox(Me.ServersError)
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks, I couldn't see that for looking!